# xml fault with dewplayer

Tags: xml, flash, upload

On my website chrisdthomas.co.uk I have installed dewplayer to play some mp3 files. A folder called portfolio contains the sounds.html file that generates the relevant webpage. Within this folder is a folder called sounds which contains the files dewplayer-playlist.swf and playlist.xml, along with a folder called mp3s which contains the mp3 files.
On my computer it works perfectly.  When I upload it half loads and says "XML Error".
If I download it back to my computer it works perfectly again!
Anyone got any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the files are in the same place on the server (eg browse to an individual swf, mp3, etc). It is also worth checking the file/folder names as these are case-sensitive on some servers.

You need to check all the paths to the resources. I can see the dewplayer-playlist.swf in the portfolio folder (http://chrisdthomas.co.uk/Portfolio/dewplayer-playlist.swf) and it is loading the playlist.xml in the same folder (as it displays the default tracklist). I'd start by editting the default playlist to point to your audio tracks.

Comment: Thanks, Martin!  The web host guys must have already changed things before you looked at it.  However, your message got me thinking about paths - I hadn't realised that I needed to enter the full URL rather than the local path.  Only problem now is it runs on Chrome and Firefox, but not IE.  If you've any thoughts on that one, I'd be grateful. Thanks again.

Comment: I just realised that I answered my own question!  I had changed the mp3 file paths to their URLs, but not the paths of the player or the playlist files.  After I changed them the website worked on IE as well as Chrome and Firefox. Thanks, Chris.